# Rational Diophantine set for the non-squares

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations

Related to Hilbert's Tenth problem.

Is there polynomial with integer coefficients $P(a,x_1,...,x_n)$
such that $P(A,X_i)=0$ has rational solutions $X_i$ iff $A$ is
not the square of integer (or as another question not the square
of rational)?

We think if $P$ is homogeneous and ask about integer solutions,
scaling the solution might cause problems: $A^2,A X_1, A X_2, ...$

Over the integers solution is trivial via Pell equation:

$$
(2+x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2+x_4^2)^2- a x_5^2=1
$$

Comment: I guess the intended meaning is "Is there $n$ and $P\in\mathbf{Z}[a,x_1,\dots,x_n]$ such that for every $A\in\mathbf{Q}$, there exists $X\in\mathbf{Q}^n$ such that $P(A,X)=0$ iff $A$ is the square of an integer"?

Comment: @YCor No, I don't ask about this. The part after "iff" is A is NOT the square of integer. The rest of the comment is correct.

Comment: OK thanks (and sorry, actually I focussed on the first quantifiers).

Comment: How about some easier sets? Like "$A>5$?

Comment: $A>5$ is too easy: $P = Q^2 + R^2$ where 
$$
Q = (A-5) (x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2 + x_4^2) - (x_5^2 + x_6^2 + x_7^2 + x_8^2)
$$
and $R = (A-5) x_9 - 1$.

Comment: Related to this question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/199191/variety-acquiring-rational-point-over-any-quadratic-extension?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies Isn't your definition for $ A > 5$ buggy? Don't you need the sums of squares nonzero?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The set $A$ of non-squares (of rationals) is Diophantine in $\mathbb{Q}$ by [1]. The set $B:=\mathbb{Q}\smallsetminus\mathbb{Z}$ is also Diophantine by [2]. The set of non-squares of integers is equal to $A\cup B$, hence Diophantine.

For a generalization of [1], see also [3].

**[EDIT]** The paper [1] treats arbitrary (non-)$n$-th powers, but the case of (non-)squares was proved earlier by Poonen [4].

[1] *Colliot-Thélène, Jean-Louis; van Geel, Jan*, [**Le complémentaire des puissances $n$-ièmes dans un corps de nombres est un ensemble diophantien**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1112/S0010437X15007368), Compos. Math. 151, No. 10, 1965-1980 (2015). [ZBL1346.14066](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1346.14066)..

[2] *Koenigsmann, Jochen*, [**Defining $\mathbb Z$ in $\mathbb Q$**](http://dx.doi.org/10.4007/annals.2016.183.1.2), Ann. Math. (2) 183, No. 1, 73-93 (2016). [ZBL1390.03032](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1390.03032)..

[3] *Dittmann, Philip*, [**Irreducibility of polynomials over global fields is diophantine**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1112/S0010437X17007977), Compos. Math. 154, 761-772 (2018). [ZBL06861881](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:06861881).

[4] 
*Poonen, Bjorn*, [**The set of nonsquares in a number field is diophantine**](http://dx.doi.org/10.4310/MRL.2009.v16.n1.a16), Math. Res. Lett. 16, No. 1, 165-170 (2009). [ZBL1183.14031](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1183.14031).

Comment: Thank you. This appears to solve an open problem: 
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/199191/variety-acquiring-rational-point-over-any-quadratic-extension/343935#343935

Comment: @joro Yes, very good point!

Comment: A comment in the other question doubts correctness about the other question, is it valid?